# When are Dive Balls extra effective?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In the original Ruby, Sapphire, and Emerald games, Dive Balls were 3.5x effective on **[underwater](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Underwater) Pokémon** (i.e., Pokémon you encounter while diving).

In every game since then, from FireRed to X and Y, Dive Balls are 3.5x effective on **water-dwelling Pokémon** (i.e., Pokémon encountered while surfing, or from fishing).

Since Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire are both recent games, and games with underwater Pokémon, when would Dive Balls be extra effective? Underwater, surfing/fishing, or both?

Neither [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/) nor [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/) appear to provide an explicit answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my testing in Alpha Sapphire, Dive Balls appear to have the 3.5× catch rate for **all water-dwelling Pokémon**, whether encountered while surfing/fishing or underwater.

First, I tested out Dive Balls on Magikarp at full HP, with no status conditions. I threw nine balls while surfing and nine while fishing. All 18 balls successfully caught the Magikarp (~100% modified catch rate), which is consistent with Dive Balls having a 3.5× catch rate. If Dive Balls were just 1x effective, it should be a ~33% modified catch rate.

I also threw nine Dive Balls at underwater Chinchou (also at full HP with no status conditions). Chinchou's catch rate with a 1× ball is theoretically 24.8%, and with a 3.5× ball 86.8%. Eight out of nine were successful (~89%), which implies that Dive Balls are 3.5× effective underwater as well.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could mention the generation of games you tested this in, as the nature of the question implies there is a difference between them.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball#Introduced_in_Generation_III), <s>in ORAS **Dive Balls** work the same as in third generation.</s>

[image]

The enhanced *catch rate* is not specified for ORAS, but is reasonable to think that it hasn't changed.

**Edit:**

According to [IGN Pokemon ORAS wiki guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Poke_Balls):
[image]

So [mic's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/229665/87579) was right, it works for all water-dwelling Pokemon.